# KendoSparklines inside table rows, where rows are added dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, kendo-ui, html-table

I have a table to which rows are added dynamically. One of the cells in each row includes a kendoSparkLine chart. Every time a new row is added, the charts in the previous rows disappear and must be redrawn. Each row has a `Knockout` click binding that sets the context of the `configuration panel` in the right (see attached image) to current `ViewModel` representing the row. So after inserting a row I can click on each row missing the chart and click `calculate` and the chart will appear.

Anyone can explain me this behavior?

How can I make sure that when adding a new row, the charts in the existing rows will still be there? Is traversing `ViewModels` in a `$.each()` loop and calling `refresh()` on each chart, the only elegant solution?

[image: Table rows that include kendoSparkLine charts]

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the `$.each()` loop I mentioned in the question, to the function that takes care of adding new rows in the `Main ViewModel`. I loop through the `observableArry()` of my `row viewmodels` and call their `calculate` function (except for the one just added). This works fine, and I knew I could do that. I wanted to avoid looping through my Array every time one adds new row to the table.
Here is some code:

```
    var rowVM = function () {
      var self = this;

      // Data
      ...
      // state
      ...

     // Operations
     ...
     self.calculate = function () {
       // logic
     }

    }

    var MainVM = function () {
        var.self = this;
        ...
        // Data
        self.rowVMs = ko.observableArray([]);

        // Operations
        ...
        self.addRow() {
          var row = new rowVM();
          self.rowVMs.push(row);
          self.setCurrentRow(row);

          $.each(self.rowVMs, function(index, vm) {
            if(vm.bulletchart) // The one just added is ignored
               vm.calculate();
          });
        }

        self.setCurrentRow(current) {
          // update currentRow observable obj
          // draw config. panel
          ...
        }

    }
```